# PHP error with a visitor counter using an image generator script

Tags: php, image, generator, counter

I have made a short visitor counter script using a .txt file instead of a database. The stats are output through an image generator script. Both scripts work fine, but when they are combined instead of the numbers from the visitor counter going up by 1, they go up by 2 each page view. Would be greatly appreciated if anyone could take the time to see what i'm doing wrong. Have literally spent a few hours trying to figure it out and had no luck.

First file (page_counter.html)

```
<?php
include 'config.php';
/* -------------------------------------------------------------------------- */
//                       HEX TO RGB CONVERTER CODE
function hex2rgb($hex) {
  $hex = str_replace("#", "", $hex);

   if(strlen($hex) == 3) {
  $r = hexdec(substr($hex,0,1).substr($hex,0,1));
  $g = hexdec(substr($hex,1,1).substr($hex,1,1));
  $b = hexdec(substr($hex,2,1).substr($hex,2,1));
   } else {
  $r = hexdec(substr($hex,0,2));
  $g = hexdec(substr($hex,2,2));
  $b = hexdec(substr($hex,4,2));
   }
   $rgb = array($r, $g, $b);

  return $rgb; 
}

//hit counter code
$counter = file_get_contents("count.txt");
$counter = trim($counter);
$counter += 1;
file_put_contents("count.txt", $counter);

//hex to rgb colour converter code
$bg_rbg = hex2rgb(BACKGROUND_COLOUR_HEX);
$txt_rbg = hex2rgb(TEXT_COLOUR_HEX);
$shadow_rbg = hex2rgb(SHADOW_COLOUR_HEX);

/* -------------------------------------------------------------------------- */
//                       IMAGE GENERACTOR CODE

header('Content-Type: image/png');

//Creates the background
$im = imagecreatetruecolor(IMAGE_WIDTH, IMAGE_HEIGHT);

//Creates the colours
$background = imagecolorallocate($im, $bg_rbg[0], $bg_rbg[1], $bg_rbg[2]);
$main_text_colour = imagecolorallocate($im, $txt_rbg[0], $txt_rbg[1], $txt_rbg[2]);
$shadow_colour = imagecolorallocate($im, $shadow_rbg[0], $shadow_rbg[1],                                                             $shadow_rbg[2]);
imagefilledrectangle($im, 0, 0, 500, 100, $background);

//Assigns a font path and font
$font = dirname(__FILE__). '/' . FONT_TYPE;

//Adds some shadow to the text
imagettftext($im, FONT_SIZE, 0, MAIN_X+1, MAIN_Y+1, $shadow_colour, $font, $counter);

//Creates the image
imagettftext($im, FONT_SIZE, 0, MAIN_X, MAIN_Y, $main_text_colour, $font, $counter);

//Using imagepng() results in clearer text compared with imagejpeg()
imagepng($im);
imagedestroy($im);
?>
```

Second file (config.php)

```
<?php
//Enter your desired background image width below
define('IMAGE_WIDTH', 90);

//Enter your desired background image height below
define('IMAGE_HEIGHT', 60);

//Enter your desired background colour below
define('BACKGROUND_COLOUR_HEX', '#FFFFFF');

//Enter your desired text colour below
define('TEXT_COLOUR_HEX', '#FF0000');

//Enter your desired shadow colour below
define('SHADOW_COLOUR_HEX', '#C0C0C0');

//Enter a font size
define('FONT_SIZE', 23);

//Enter the X coordinates of the main text below
define('MAIN_X', 20);

//Enter the Y coordinates of the main text below
define('MAIN_Y', 23);


//Enter your desired font below
define('FONT_TYPE', 'arial.ttf');
?>
```

Third file is called count.txt and is where the visitor count is stored. Start it off with 0 or your desired number.

Fourth file is just a font file, in my case arial.tff

Comment: You've not by any chance called the script twice on your page? Might sound daft but if you're trying to display the image twice on the page then this would increment the counter twice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

have solved the issue. Its a random bug i think in PHP but the problem was to do with the files, page_counter was changed to .php then it was just included on an index.html. really strange issue but its all working now. would like to thank everyone for their help.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably not the best solution, but how about you try +0.5f instead of +1?
If it actually does +1 then you know your script is being called twice. If it does +1.5 then there's a +1 somewhere else in some other code.